# npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org during Dockerizing a Node.js web app

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

Hi im trying dockerizing my project in node and react, mi operative system is CentOS 8.1,version node 12.16.1 and Docker version 19.03.8. I follow the tutorial from node https://nodejs.org/fr/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/ my docker file is the next

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

and .dockerignore is

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

when i build i have error in step 4 npm install

```
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 922fd6d848a1
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-3.0.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
```

I hope can help me, thanks for reading

Comment: The EAI_AGAIN is a DNS error. Are you by chance behind a proxy? Maybe checkout: https://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

Comment: Configure my static ip and the dns server is configured 8.8.8.8, ping where it is correct, i used the current version npm. Any other sugestion?

Comment: Can you run `npm install` from outside docker?

Comment: Yes, I can run npm without problem, but I can read that maybe it can be through my connection or provider, the centos default proxy is disabled

Answer (score 6):

if someday any have this problem you can resolve with this
 `docker build . --network host -t mytag ..` 
or another suggestion suggestion you can check the following link 
https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/issues/270