# Docker compose with node and mysql and pareameters --network host

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

today i can solve with error while creating my image for the node, i had a problem for step 4 of npm installation, but i solved with this

```
docker build . --network host -t mytag
```

now i want to use docker compose for my app, mysql, node, and react, but in node i use knex, any suggestion for execute knex migrate: latest, my docker file for build image mysql is:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydata
EXPOSE 3307
```

and docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    build: ./Db

  hosting-backend:
    build: .
    command: cd ServerBackEnd && knex migrate:latest
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"

  hosting-front-end:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

but for create de image for node i use --network host but i don´t have idea execute image with this parameter and I'm not sure about the command that execute knex migrate latest, I hope you can help me about this, thanks.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're encountering; can you attach an actual error message and a [mcve]?  I feel like I most often see `--network host` as a workaround for some other underlying issue; have you tried to solve the actual problem?  (If you run the backend container with `network: host` it won't be able to reach the database container.)

Comment: I had  a problem when create image for back end, the error was `npm ERR! solicitud a https://registry.npmjs.org` and i resolving with `--network host`
I read about the problem, I configured my dns docker, and in another operating system it worked correctly on the same network, the only solution that worked for me was `--netowork host ` in image, this is my question about the problem  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129060/npm-err-request-to-https-registry-npmjs-org-during-dockerizing-a-node-js-web